# Change Labels of Views in Fragments or Activity using Strings file based on some condition

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a application with `Activity` and `Fragment`.I am managing multiple workflows in same application.The same app is used for multiple domain where the same `Fragments` are going to be used but based on domain which I will get from Api Service I need to set labels in Fragments.How to achieve this to eliminate the problem of building the same screen for every domain separately. Can it be achieved on same `Fragment` by changing only the labels of Views using some condition ?

Comment: What do you mean by "label"? You could try to post the code of the layout.

Comment: It simple means suppose in Fragment I have the hint to Edittext as Enter Name, but  if my business type chaned which I received from API, i might want to set the hint as Enter full name.

Comment: Bind the the TextView and you can call **setText**